# Nest Thermostat Wiring problem - Heat does not work

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, nest

I recently replaced my old American Standard thermostat with Google Nest. Cooling works fine but Heat does not work and simply goes into an unending loop of 'delayed: will start in 2:30 secs'

I think the problem is in wiring, and especially blue wire.
My wiring diagram
[image]

Old Thermostat:
[image]

New Nest Thermostat (If B wire in *OB, cool works and heat doesnt. If B wire is in C, nothing works)
[image]

Board in the Attic:
[image]

Also the wire connector test looks like this. Google search said the lin is way too high, but not sure what it means.
[image]

Anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Update:
updated the wiring diagram with a bigger picture.
I bilieve i may have a heat pump outside the house. The outside installation looks like what google says is a heatpump.
Also,
zoomed out picture of furnace wiring:
[image]

Comment: Is this a heat pump?  Any idea what Iin and PS mean?  Voltage should be 24v, so something is going on.

Comment: I am not sure myself what those mean.

Comment: @Gadam -- what make and model is your furnace?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I believe its American Standard Freedom 80 Comfort R. I just uploaded a zoomed out picture in the OP

Comment: There might be a wiring diagram on the inside of the door that could help.  Also, you need a voltmeter to check the voltage between R and C and the voltage between R and the metal chassis of the air handler.

Comment: Huh, wait, what, you do not know if you have an A/C unit or a heat pump?  These are important distinctions... it will be impossible for anyone to give you an answer unless you can positively tell us what you have.

Comment: Also, the thermostat has to be properly set up for the type of system you have.  You _probably_ don't have a heat pump based on the wiring that I see.  The only way to visually tell on the outside unit is looking through the fan grill on top and looking for a changeover valve, but then you need to know what that looks like.  The thermostat wiring going to the outside unit is also different.  A standard AC has two wires (like it appears you have), and a heat pump will have 3 or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your B wire is a C wire, so connect it to C at the thermostat

The wire you identified as B in your drawing is actually your C wire (we can tell because your A/C condensing unit is wired between Y and it, with only two wires headed off to it), so it needs to be connected to C on your Nest, not the */O/B terminal.

Comment: I came to to same conclusion, considering that I see the blue wire coming from the thermostat is connected to the B/C on the board. BUT if I connect the B to the C on Nest, it doesn't work. Both Heat and cool do not work. If I connect B to */O/B then Cool works but Heat does not work.

Comment: @Gadam -- that's bizarre -- have you tried removing the jumper from Y to O on your control board?

Comment: No I haven't tried that. I can try. What is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: @Gadam -- for a non-heat-pump system, there's really no reason for that jumper to be there -- a furnace control that didn't work correctly unless B was connected to something would be extremely astonishing to say the least, as it wouldn't work in the most common case

Comment: Ok I removed the Y-O jumper. Cool continues to work fine as before, but heat is still not working. When in heat the outside unit is still running and the vents inside are blowing cold air. I confirmed I don’t have a heat pump based on googling the model number and no visual horizontal valve pipe in the ac unit. I eventually removed the w1-w2 jumper as well, and just connected white to w1. No change from above.

Comment: Are you getting 24V from Y to C when your thermostat is set for heat?

Comment: My multimeter is coming tomorrow from Amazon, will check it. Just to confirm, I check this on the Furnace board correct?

Comment: @Gadam yes, correct

Comment: ok I tested it - In both modes(heat and cold), the readings are same: 24v for Y-C, R-C, G-C; nothing from W-C. My understanding is in Heat mode the W-C shd have 24 (and nothing on Y-C) and vice-versa for Cooling mode. Is that correct?

Comment: @Gadam -- correct. It sounds like your thermostat is set in heat pump mode when it should be set up for a conventional forced-air system -- check the system type setting

Comment: Yes, finally it works! The problem was in the Google Home setup. It asked me what wires do I have, and I selected RGYW and B, But when I switched to selecting RGYW and C because my Blue wire is actually a C wire. The fact that in the old thermostat (see pic above) the Blue wire was connected to B confused things a bit. Thanks @ThreePhaseEel